# Configurar Babel en mi equipo de trabajo

Tags: javascript, windows10, vscode, babeljs

Estoy tratando de seguir unos tutoriales para aprender las mejoras y cambios que trae ES6, pero me he tomado con esto de el uso de un transpilador, en este caso, Babel.js.

En la pagina de Babel ahora para instalarlo recomiendan, para el `CLI`, la siguiente linea desde la consola

`npm install -g babel-cli`
`npm install --save-dev babel-cli`

He instalado ambas, y cuando quiero transpilar desde la consola, por ejemplo usando de la siguiente forma

`babel --watch file-es6.js --out-file file-es5.js`

Y crea el archivo, pero no transpilado, solo hace una copia exacta.

Estoy usando VS Code, y me aparecen los siguientes mensajes de errores o alertas

```
 'Advertencia'
message: ''template literal syntax' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6'). (W119)'
at: '3,10'
source: 'jshint'
```

Debido a que segun comprendo, no tiene activado el reconocimiento de ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una advertencia de `JSHint` y para corregirlo necesitas un archivo `.jshintrc` cual indicas la versión de tu sintaxis de JavaScript.

```
{
  "esversion": 6
}
```

o inicias el archivo individualmente con:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/

// resto de código
```

Comment: el archivo puede llamarse de manera cualquier?, lo que importa es solo la extensión?

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales - no.. el archivo se llama: `.jshintrc` no es una extensión es un archivo oculto.. y tiene que estar en el root (ruta principal) de tu aplicación

Comment: Ya lo hago y te comento

Comment: funciona bien, gracias, disculpa, sabes el por que no podría estar transpilando los archivos de forma correcta?

Comment: De nada... y a tu pregunta... es mejor que creases un nuevo post... ya que no podemos utilizar los comentarios como tipo chat... y con mucho gusto echaré un vistazo... saludos

Comment: Ya mismo lo hago